# Connection Error while creating ADF linked service

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i m trying to create new linked service in azure data factory, where i have created sql db already. attach the error message in the link
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XG003.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to connect to a SQL Database that is behind a firewall. If you allow the IP address (in your case it is 20.42.2.58 as per the screenshot) your linked service should work. Navigate to Firewall and Virtual Networks blade of your SQL Server and add IP address, the start IP and the end IP should be the same.

A second option would be to use "Allow Azure services and resources to access this server"  - set this option to Yes.

[image: Firewall rule - add IP address]